# Nested functions to create hierarchical structure

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create hierarchical result with callbacks.

This is my function structure:

```
el('root', function(){

  el('users', function(){
    el('show');
  });

  el('products');

});
```

The result I want is:

```
assert.equal(result, [ 'root', 'root_users', 'root_users_show', 'root_products' ] );
```

I got pretty far in my implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/5ur5u/ The problem I have is that I am increasing my depth each time el is called. It works fine until it reaches products. Because show puts depth on 3 it means that products will be added at the end of show.

So if anybody can give me a hand or point me into the right direction that would be great.

Comment: This is tricky because `el` cannot (in a sane way) know in which level it was called. You might be better off passing a function `el` to the callback, which is different each time.

Comment: You mean el('root', function(el){ el('users' ) } );?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you are asking for

```
var names = [];
var result = [];

function el(name, f)
{
    names.push(name);
    result.push(names.join("_"));
    f && f();
    names.pop();
}

el("root", function(){
    el("users", function(){
        el("show")
    });
    el("products");
});

alert(result);
```

Comment: Bah, was so proud of what I had but this is a million times better.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. You just need to decrement the depth at the end. See http://jsfiddle.net/Z2qsy/

Rather than

```
depth += 1;
fn();
```

Do this

```
depth += 1;
fn();
depth -= 1;
```

Comment: Think you forgot to click update in jsfiddler. Here's a link with a working example with your patch. http://jsfiddle.net/Z2qsy/1/

Answer (score 1):

<del>Since `el` is the very same function each time it is called, there is no way to distinguish between it being called in one level (`show`) or another (`products`). You can increment the level each time `el` is called, but there is no way to know when to decrement it because there is not something like the "opposite" of calling in JavaScript.</del>

A slightly better option is to pass a new function to the callback (you could give it the same name `el`), which is different so that each level has its own `el` function. That way, the result can be built correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/5ur5u/2/.

```
var result = [];

function el(name, fn) {
    result.push(name); // add current name

    if(fn) { // if there is a function
        fn(function(name2, fn2) { // call the function with a new function
            el(name + "_" + name2, fn2); // which calls `el` recursively
                                         // with the names combined
        });
    }
}

el('root', function(el) {

  // this `el` refers to the function passed as declared above,
  // which is not the same one as the initial `el`
  el('users', function(el) {
    el('show');
  });

  el('products');

});
```

Comment: +1 I like it how your solution simplifies the library code but makes the url map a little more verbose (the extra el parameter).